# How to do Partial Page reloads?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax, iframe

I have a set of pages which look like this --

[image: webpage_layout]

Links I click in the top section cause the `links`, and `content` sections to change (as intended), but it also refreshes the `bottom` section.

I want the `bottom` section to remain unchanged (clicking on `links` in the `top` section must not refresh the `bottom`) between these pages.

Are iframes the only way of doing this? Is there a way of doing this in ASP.NET using some AJAX control?

Someone please suggest the best way of going about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the information using AJAX methods and replace only parts of the DOM.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Here are some decent tutorials:

http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/

http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/

Comment: So I'd have one main page with a static bottom section, which fetches and replaces pages, as link clicks occur... ?

Comment: @anirudh4444 - Yes, that's right. Essentially you're just using Javascript to replace parts of the page that are requested by Ajax.

Comment: See here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Ajax_mode What you're doing is very similar to having tabs and loading the tab content with Ajax.

Comment: Any easier way of doing this in an ASP.NET environment? Because I have organized the site into several levels of master pages, I'd have to change all that to use the parent page.

Comment: Also, please do tell me how this is better/worse than the iframe approach.

Comment: Well, I know there's http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/. Another option other than an IFRAME may be a good ol' FRAME, with the top two parts one frame, the bottom one another. If you want the bottom to scroll with the content, then you'd need to either load the content with AJAX or use two IFRAMEs.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX for sure. Check jQuery library especially the $.get method.

Comment: So I'd have one main page with a static bottom section, which fetches and replaces pages, as link clicks occur... ?

Comment: Yesh Yesh. In that case look at $.load will be more efficient if you are not posting values. Have a DIV and change its content on clicks.

Comment: Also, please do tell me how this is better/worse than the iframe approach.

Comment: iframes can many times screw up the layout of the page in some browsers. Also, iFrame is a completely a different page in its own right. iFrames are useful when you want to load something from a different site and embed it.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way may be to use ASP.NET [UpdatePanel](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/).

Comment: Could you please explain a little more about how I can use that with the layout I have? (See question)

Comment: You put links and content inside update panel. Each link should be a LinkButton control, which triggers a back-end method which updates the content.